# XAMPP Project only shows blank page but other project works fine

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost

My project was working before I shared my screen through skype. My skype is not using port 80. I restarted my computer and it still doesn't work.  My other web project is working fine though.

Comment: have you checked the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a totally blank screen rather than an Apache error or an error from your browser?

If so, and if other sites are working, it's unlikely to be related to Skype.  I know Skype uses the default HTTP and HTTPS ports, but that is not the case if Skype isn't running and after a restart, like you say.

The most probable issue is that there is a server-side error in your WordPress site.  If `error_reporting` is switched off and a fatal error occurs then you will simply get a blank screen.  Look for the `error_log` file (usually in the same directory, `/xampp/apache/logs/error.log`, or wherever it is set in your `vhosts.conf` file), and if it isn't present make sure `error_reporting` is set to a reasonable level in your PHP config, and that `display_errors` is set to `On`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. My site just started to become blank after I used the sharescreen function in skype. This has happened to me before. What I did was I had to reinstall the back up of my site to get it to appear. This is really weird. By the way, I set all the error reporting in php.ini to on and I still haven't got anything. Just a blank page. :(